# Play - Scala Template, access list element

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have two arraylists, `Tweets: ArrayList[TweetObject]` and

```
cluster_sizes: ArrayList[Integer]
```

What i want to do is this but i couldn't find a way to do it, I don't want to mess with the TweetObject class to add what is in the cluster_sizes array.

```
@for((tweet,index) <- Tweets.zipWithIndex){
    @form(action = routes.Application.clean_and_move_on()){
        <td>@index</td>
        <td>@cluster_sizes[@index]</td>
        <td>@tweet.owner</td>
```

Is there any way to access this list like `@cluster_sizes[@index]` ?

Comment: Remember your accessing array in scala not java. @cluster_sizes(index)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by saying "I don't want to mess with the `TweetObject`class to add what is in the `cluster_sizes` array"

Comment: I can add this information to the TweetObject class and access it like TweetObject.cluster_size but they are not really related and i didn't want to do it just to show it on the User Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '@' character indicates the beginning of a code block, you don't have to use it twice in a row. Also you have to get the element in scala-style, hence:

```html
<td>@cluster_sizes(index)</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have no experience with scala at all and thought @ indicates a variable.